# Number input in cordova-dialogs-plugin

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to find a answer to this but yet I've found nothing to address it.

I'm using ionicPopup to ask the user for some input. This popup has a `inputType` property that if it is `number` it will display the number keypad. This is the best way to the user since I'm asking for numbers only.

For `ionicPopup` I'm using:

```
$ionicPopup.prompt({
            title: 'Weight',
            template: 'Add new weight ' + '(' + $scope.measurementProfile + ')',
            inputType: 'number',
            inputPlaceholder: convertDisplay(item.weight),
            cancelText: 'Cancel',
            okText: 'Ok'
        }).then(function (res) {
          ....
```

But then I switch to [cordova-dialogs-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs) that with these lines (not mine)

```
// Override the default HTML alert with native dialog - requires the cordova dialogs plugin
        if (navigator.notification) {
            window.alert = function (message) {
                navigator.notification.alert(
                    message,    // message
                    null,       // callback
                    "MyApp",      // title
                    'OK'        // buttonName
                    );
            };
        }
```

you get a native style. So:

```
navigator.notification.prompt('Add new weight ' + '(' + $scope.measurementProfile + ')', 
            function(res){
                add(res, id);
            },
            'MyApp', ['Ok', 'Cancel'],'');
```

Will get this nice and native alert/prompt but it does not supports an `inputType` like ionicPopup.

[image: Native iOS prompt style]

I'm lost. Need I edit cordova-dialogs-plugin to accept number only? I've read the docs and found nothing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Esselans,
 Google: [phonegap android force numeric keyboard](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonegap+android+force+numeric+keyboard)
FWIW: *Cordova* will work in place of phonegap.

Your answer is the first article: [Triggering Numeric Keyboards with HTML5](http://blog.pamelafox.org/2012/05/triggering-numeric-keyboards-with-html5.html)

The answer to your question is: `<input type="number" step="0.01">`

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not using a HTML input tag. That plugin shows an alert prompt asking for a number. It uses native alert of the browser and is not customisable.

Comment: Have you considered creating your own Popup? It is trivial using HTML5. Here is an example I have called [mobileui-popup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/mobileui-popup). It may or may not work for you. clone the code, and build with *Phonegap Build* **OR** clone and convert to CLI. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the CDVNotification.m of the plugin you can add a line here:

```
 if ([dialogType isEqualToString:DIALOG_TYPE_PROMPT]) {
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
                 textField.text = defaultText;
                 //Use the number pad by adding this line
                 textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad; 
                }];
            }
```